# "It compounds over time"

Tags: word-meaning

I would like you to kindly let me or confirm with me about the use of the verb "compound" at the title. It's from [this article.](https://www.yahoo.com/finance/news/pay-equity-republicans-democrats-050000963.html)

Kim Churches, CEO of the American Association of University Women (AAUW), says,

> “Women are faced with the pay gap and the leadership gap every single day as they pursue their educational dreams, enter the workforce, and continue throughout their careers,” Churches told Yahoo Finance. “**It compounds over time.**

According to Merriam Unabridged, the definition of the verb "compound" are

> Transitive
>
> 1:  to put together (as elements, ingredients, or parts) to form a whole :  combine, unite
>
> 2
>   a :  to form or make up (as a composite product) by combining different elements, ingredients, or parts
>   
>   
>   b obsolete :  compose, create
>
> 3
>   :  to settle amicably :  adjust by agreement :  discharge (an obligation) upon terms different from those which were stipulated, claimed, or demanded (as when a smaller sum is accepted than was asked) :  compromise
>
> 4
>   a :  to increase by geometric progression or by an increment that itself increases
>   
>   b :  to cause to multiply at a faster and faster rate
>   c :  to add to :  augment
>
> 5
>   :  to forbear prosecution of (an offense) for a consideration
>
> 6
>   :  to wind the field magnets of (a dynamo) so as to make excitable by both a shunt and a series current
>
> 7
>   :  to combine (as forces and velocities) into a single resultant
>
> intransitive verb
>
> 1
>   :  to unite into or as if into a compound
>
> 2
>   :  to come to terms of agreement or payment :  settle by a compromise :  agree

It would be, I guess, the 4a of the transitive verb, am I correct?

Thank you so much for your kind advice in advance (m_m)

Comment: 4a is correct, but why guess - analyse it so you are sure.

Comment: @SolarMike My apology. I had somewhat a mild uncomfortable feeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your assumption is accurate.

If you're unfamiliar with compound as a financial term, this link might help you gain clarity.

[compound interest](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/compoundinterest.asp)

Comment: I truly appreciate your answer. Though my assumption was luckily correct, I am very sorry I had some "spooky" feeling if I am really correct or not. Anyway thanks (m_m).